# apache Axis2 SOAP : What is 'DEBUG_FRAME' means?

Tags: spring, debugging, soap, console

I am new in SOAP.

I made an web application which based on Spring 3.2.8.
I imported some of apache axis2 libraries.

My application works well but I can find some "DEBUG_FRAME"s in my console.

```
15:26:32.440 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.a.axis2.description.AxisService - DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString(JavaUtils.java:564)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.mapActionToOperation(AxisService.java:821)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.addOperation(AxisService.java:671)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.createAnonymousService(ServiceClient.java:277)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:172)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
    DEBUG_FRAME = com.zinnaworks.wepg.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:145)
    DEBUG_FRAME = com.zinnaworks.wepg.utils.CCSSoapMessage.getProgramInfo(CCSSoapMessage.java:160)
    DEBUG_FRAME = com.zinnaworks.wepg.soap.SOAPDataLoader.loadPrograms(SOAPDataLoader.java:208)
    DEBUG_FRAME = com.zinnaworks.wepg.soap.SOAPDataLoader.loadData(SOAPDataLoader.java:41)
    DEBUG_FRAME = com.zinnaworks.wepg.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:43)
    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    DEBUG_FRAME = sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    DEBUG_FRAME = javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    DEBUG_FRAME = javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    DEBUG_FRAME = org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    DEBUG_FRAME = java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is it OK to ignore since it is not a "WARN" or "EXCEPTION"?(I found an "ERROR" in messages but I am not sure it is real error or just debugging log) I have never show this type of message before.

I need to know what this "DEBUG_FRAME" means.
Thanks:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the [source code of `org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService`](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_6/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/description/AxisService.java#L821) and (from the line where all that stack trace starts being printed out), [`org.apache.axis2.util.JavaUtils.callStackToString()` method](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_6/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/util/JavaUtils.java#L563), it seems this is just a more detailed debug message.

Basically, Axis2 prints out DEBUG messages and for some of them, it also prints out the full call stack with it. `callStackToString()` method it's calling another method passing in a new `RuntimeException` as parameter. But this exception is not something generated by code and it doesn't show a problem, it is just a way of getting a hold of the calling stack so that the DEBUG message to be more detailed. And those "DEBUG_FRAME"s are a replacement for "at" from a normal Java stack trace. Axis2 code is actually [replacing "at" with "DEBUG_FRAME"](https://github.com/apache/axis2-java/blob/1_6/modules/kernel/src/org/apache/axis2/util/JavaUtils.java#L582).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Linked pages are very helpful. Thanks again :D

Comment: How to remove this DEBUG_FRAME from my log file?